# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException:Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Actually i am new to Association in hibernate, this is problem
occurred due to wrong configuration?

`SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();`

above query which i used in main class is also not working ,
but it shows same thing...??

**Hibernate Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</property>
    <property name="connection.user">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="Pojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Address.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Address Entity Mapping**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.firoz.Pojo.Address"table="name">
        <id name = "Addid" column="Addressid">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">ps</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
    <property name="roadno" column="roadno" length="10" />
    <property name="Street" column="street" length="10"/>
        <one-to-one name="ps" class="com.firoz.Pojo.Pojo" cascade="all"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Pojo Entity Mappiing**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class  name="com.firoz.Pojo.Pojo" table="name">
    <id name="eid" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <property name="ename" column="name" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="sal" column="sal" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**I get the following error.**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.firoz.main.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.org Nested exception: hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Is "mysql" the name of your database??

Comment: Hibernate can resolve the DTDs locally (without a network connection). were you working offline when this happened?

Comment: yup...that is my database name.......@NewBee Developer

Answer (score 0):

In the address entity mapping xml file, you are missing a space before table attribute.
Make the below change and try:

```
<class name="com.firoz.Pojo.Address"table="name">
```

to

```
 <class name="com.firoz.Pojo.Address" table="name">
```

Comment: @khajafiroz Are you getting the same exception or a different one?